# Jquery count all empty fields

Tags: jquery, html-input

Is there a way in jquery to count all empty inputs and textareas in a form, for the following types

checkbox,
date,
datetime, 
email, 
month, 
number, 
radio,
tel,
text

because every form has a js variable maxInput.
if maxInput is 6 (form has 6 inputs)
then if you count the inputs and it is 6 i know that all is filled.
Does anybody knows how to complete this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for a variable/dynamic number of the inputs you specified given a form with class 'test-form'. Just be sure you set value="" on the default option of your selects. Checking if the radio button group is unselected is a little trickier:

```
var emptyTextCheckboxAndSelect = $('.test-form input, .test-form select').filter(function(){

    if($(this).attr('type') === "radio"){
        return false;//we'll check for empty radio groups elsewhere        
    }

    if($(this).attr('type') === "checkbox"){
        return !$(this).prop("checked");
    }

    return !$(this).val();//this only works for select if default option explicitly sets value=""

}).length;


var radioNameHash = {},
    uncheckedRadioButtonGroups = 0;

$('.test-form input[type="radio"]').each(function(i, radioButton){

    if(radioNameHash[$(this).attr('name')] === undefined){
        uncheckedRadioButtonGroups++;
        radioNameHash[$(this).attr('name')] = true;
    }

    if($(this).prop("checked") === true){
        uncheckedRadioButtonGroups--;
    }
});

var totalUnfilledFields = emptyTextCheckboxAndSelect + uncheckedRadioButtonGroups;

alert(totalUnfilledFields);
```

Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qLedcr82/1/

As an aside, it's typically a best practice to set a default value for radio button groups which would render that part of the solution useless.

Answer (score 5):

Suppose all `inputs` has a class named: `yourClass` then this may help you:

```
$('.yourClass').filter(function(){
return !$(this).val();
}).length;
```

Comment: Does this also count radio and select boxes?

Comment: Select, yes—checkbox and radio unlikely. Also keep in mind this will return a false positive if the value in the field is the number 0.

Comment: $( 'input[type=radio]' ) will get all radio buttons.

Comment: Finding how many radio button groups are unselected is a bit more difficult than that.